# XSLT level grouping on multiple documents

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have multiple documents with following structure

Document 1

```
<para>
    <title>title1</title>
    <para>
        <title>title2</title>
        <para>
            <title>title3</title>
        </para>
    </para>
    <para>
        <title>title4</title>
        <para>
            <title>title5</title>
        </para>
    </para>
</para>
```

Document 2

```
<para1>
    <title>title6</title>
    <para1>
        <title>title7</title>
    </para1>
    <para1>
       <title>title8</title>
    </para1>
</para1>
```

I want an output which would look something like this

```
1. title1
1.1 title2
1.1.1 title3
1.2 title4
1.2.1 title5
2. title6
2.1 title7
2.2 title8
```

I have used `xsl:number` but I am not able to get the desired result

Comment: To use `xsl:number` or (if you can use XSLT 3) an accumulator it is best to have a single document so you could consider to simply create an intermediary document in a variable that merges the `para` and `para1` elements into one tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you merge the nodes into an intermediary tree you can use `xsl:number` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:variable name="merged-tree">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*, $doc2/*"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="para | para1">
    <div>
      <xsl:number level="multiple" count="para | para1" format="1.1.1 "/> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$merged-tree/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="doc2">
<para1>
    <title>title6</title>
    <para1>
        <title>title7</title>
    </para1>
    <para1>
       <title>title8</title>
    </para1>
</para1>    
  </xsl:param>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives

```
<div>1 
    title1
    <div>1.1 
        title2
        <div>1.1.1 
            title3
        </div>
   </div>
   <div>1.2 
        title4
        <div>1.2.1 
            title5
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div>2 title6<div>2.1 title7</div>
   <div>2.2 title8</div>
</div>
```

For an XSLT 2.0 processor replace the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` declaration with the identity transformation template e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```